# Ubuntu 22.04, Pro installed, but getting: "Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled." message

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-pro

It is installed, and the services are enabled. Do you have any suggestions about how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Where is the message?

Comment: I ended up reinstalling OS...  thanks